# jQuery Create Multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having a heck of a time trying to figure out how to create a multidimensional array in jQuery.

I instantiate the array outside of the loop.

```
 <script>
 var myArray = [];
 </script>
```

Inside of my loop I want to add the array elements.

```
 i = 0
 [loop start]
      <script>
      myArray[i][$row[sku]] = $row[qty]; // sku might be repeated will this cause an issue? You will see in the error below "295518" is repeated...
      <script>
 [loop end]
```

In my source code it looks like this:

```
 <script>
 myArray[ 1 ][ 295518 ] = 122;
 </script>
```

Then I run this at the end outside the loop...

```
 <script>
 console.log( myArray );
 </script>
```

I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '295518' of undefined 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '70252' of undefined 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '295518' of undefined
```

What I am doing wrong in setting up this array? Thanks!

Comment: show your code of array...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

you can do so:

```
var a = [];
a[0] = [1,2,3]; 
a[1] = [4,5,6]; 

a[1][1] it is 5
```

Comment: Excellent, a tiny example like this, of actual code that works, is ideal - this solved what I was looking for where 45mins of Ggl and lots of SE pages didn't -- *thank* you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a two dimensional array,

You can define it like this

`var myArray = ['',''];`